# jupyter notebook unrecognized arguments \ \

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to follow this [tutorial](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) to connect google colab to a local runtime. However, when entering this command

```
jupyter notebook \ --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \ --port=8888 \ --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

I receive the following error

```
jupyter-notebook: error: unrecognized arguments: \ \
```

I am using anaconda on a windows machine, jupyter notebook works fine on its own, but this command fails when following the tutorial above.

Comment: Did you follow step 2 in those instructions? This is in a terminal, right? Are you actually entering those instructions on one line? That looks like a multi-line command (basically, you can remove the backslashes and *then* put it all on one line).

Answer (score 2):

In the tutorial, those backslashes are used just before the newlines to extend the single command to multiple lines. Either do the same thing - newline after the backslash - or, if you want to just write code on a single line, remove the backslashes.

```
jupyter notebook \
  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
  --port=8888 \
  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

or

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888 --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```